# Why is the size of std::string relatively larger than std::vector?

Tags: c++, sizeof

The following code example that is here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c27c250819b72a01 shows 32 Bytes for `std::string` while 24 Bytes for `std::vector<int>`.

Though this may change from one platform to another, I expect to see sizeof `std::string` always larger than `std::vector`.

The question is why?

Comment: What Sam refers to is that std::string already has a (not seperately allocated) for small strings, vector does not it only contains "metadata" and a pointer to a buffer. string will only start allocating on the heap when a string is too long to fit in the buffer. (called small string optimization).

Comment: The sentence should have started with : "What Sam refers to is that std::string already has buffer"

Comment: Libstdc++'s string is implemented as you'd expect and in the same way as vector with a pointer, a size and a capacity but for the small string optimisation string has an extra 8 bytes allowing storage of slightly larger strings before using the heap https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/ce2188e4320cbb46d6246bd3f478ba20440c62f3/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L205